# Calculating mean slope of lines based on DEM?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, dem, line, slope

I have a DEM and a line vector shapefile (also available in PostGIS) and I need to calculate the mean slope of every line. Direction of the slope (positive or negative) is not important.

That means I should assign the DEM raster values of the start and end vertex to two new attributes (e.g. *alti_a* and *alti_b*). Then it would be possible to use field calculator and calculate the slope.

How can I do this? Are there alternative solutions?

Comment: are you willing to move to PostGIS completely, including the upload of your DEM to the DB (mind you, this might be a little time intensive, depending on the DEM's size and/or if you're not familiar)? there are options in QGIS, but once imported in PostGIS you could do that in one query and easily repeat it if necessary.

Comment: @ThingumaBob I am...but I'm new to PostGIS and it took me quite a while to install the server...so I assume I'd need to follow this [RastertoPostGIS] (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58619/how-to-import-qgis-raster-into-postgis) and then this [ExtractElevationValues] (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129503/how-to-extract-elevation-values-at-line-start-and-end-points-from-a-dem/151586)

Comment: btw: what do I do wrong with the mini-Markdown formatting for the links?

Comment: -> no space between ] and (

Comment: thx. And am I right with the two links?

Comment: yep, that would make for the right workflow. AFAIK, for within QGIS, you will have to go the detour of extracting the line's vertices to a point layer and assign the DEM values to them via [Point Sampling Tool](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pointsamplingtool/) or [SAGA Grid Values to Point](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.5/shapes_grid_3.html) (from the SAGA toolbox)

Comment: I already tried to go with SAGA Grid values to Point but wasn't able then to calculate the slope between the points (As I don't need to calculate every connection but only those neighbouring on the roads...

Comment: I understand overall expectation is PostGIS solution. My answer is for, just in case, you feel comfortable with QGIS Field Calculator.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have DEM height (z) at both ends as `"z1"`, `"z2"` fields respectively in your line layer, try this expression in the Field Calculator.

```
degrees(atan2(abs("z2"-"z1"), sqrt(($x_at(-1)-$x_at(0))^2 + ($y_at(-1)-$y_at(0))^2)))
```

[image]

Comment: thx for your explanation! I understand the field calculator expression. But how can I create the z1 and z1 fields out of the DEM?

Comment: @Kevkev770 As you have z information through SAGA `Grid values to Point` tool, z values are stored in point layer. Join line and points together. To be honest I usually manually copy and paste z-values as I do not have too many lines.

Comment: do you know how I could determine which point is z1 and which one is z2? I have way too many points to do it manually.

Comment: @Kevkev770 Because of `abs()`, either will do. It is still better sticking to your own rule, just to avoid potential confusion (for future updates).

Comment: ok...I tried using _Join attribute by location_ but then I only have one value Z-Value for each line. Would you mind telling me what tool I should use?

Comment: @Kevkev770 Do we have to continue this dialogue until you finish whole process? This is not a training site.

Comment: no, we don't. thanks for your help! I really appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

To get the elevation / z values from the DEM for (all) the vertices of your line geometries, you can use the ***Drape (set Z value from raster)*** QGIS algorithm.

You can then use ***Extract specific vertices*** to get to the start (0) and end (-1) points of the lines.

(or you can extract the start and end points first and then get the z values from the DEM)

In your calculations you can then use the `z(geom)` function to get the `z` (elevation) values from the geometries.